# How can I map multiple instances to the same war file in Weblogic?

Tags: apache, web-applications, war, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

is it possible to deploy mutiple instance of same war so that it can be accessed by different context?

http:// localhost:7001/app1 points to --> app.war

http:// localhost:7001/app2 points to --> app.war

http:// localhost:7001/app3 points to --> app.war

I have to use Weblogic server which is a constraint. I know it works with Jetty but cannot use it though :-(

Comment: Since your question's tags include `apache`, please clarify if you are using an Apache web server in front of your WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the weblogic.xml defines the context root for your web application. If it is the same war with the same weblogic.xml, the 3 deployments will have context root conflict. You should look into the deployment plan, which can replace the context root defined in the weblogic.xml. For each deployment, specify the war file and the plan.xml either through the admin console or the command line deployer.